# Should use CDialog or CFramewnd to build drawing application?

Tags: c++, mfc, drawing

I'm reading Chapter "Drawing with GDI" in book "Programming Windows with MFC".
I saw that CFramewnd or Document/View are used in all examples of this chapter.
I think that maybe CDialog is not proper way to build drawing application.

So, my question is: should I use CDialog or CFramewnd or Docuemnt/View to build drawing application?
And could you give me some difference between CDialog and CFramewnd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CDialog` is intended to be used as the base class for dialogs - relatively shortlived windows to communicate relatively simple bits of information. There are a bunch of standard dialogs (e.g. File Open dialog) but for most information, you'd write your own and base that on `CDialog`.

So it's not intended as the main window for a normal application. Yet, if your application is a simple tool - say switch a single registry value from 0 to 1 - it may make sense to implement it as just a dialog. But a drawing application? That's not a dialog.